# Class that worked in Delphi fails to run in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

The below class implementation works fine in Delphi, however it fails when running in Lazarus.

The purpose is to run a timer asynchronously.

```
// Declaration
type
  TTimerEvents = class
  private
    class procedure tonTimer(Sender: TObject);
  end;

// Implementation
class procedure TTimerEvents.tonTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  vTag: string;
begin
  (Sender as TTimer).Enabled := false;
  vTag := 'Tag_' + IntToStr((Sender as TTimer).Tag);
  // more stuff here
end;                                 

// Call
procedure TmainForm.actTON(i: integer);
var
  t: TTimer;
begin
  t := TTimer.Create(mainForm);
  t.Interval := StrToInt(vTime) * 1000;
  t.Tag := vTag;
  t.OnTimer := TTimerEvents.tonTimer; //<<<----HERE
  t.Enabled := True;
  // more stuff here
end;
```

Error msg:

> fmmain.pas(371,33) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "tonTimer"

If I include `Timer1 as Sender` then I get a different error msg:

> fmmain.pas(371,49) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "untyped", expected "<procedure variable type of procedure(TObject) of object;Register>"

Comment: Use `t.OnTimer := @TTimerEvents.tonTimer;`. The compiler thinks you're trying to call the event instead of trying to assign it as an event handler. The problem occasionally happens in older versions of Delphi as well.

Comment: [Code Conversion Guide 2.2.11.1: When assigning an event handling entry point, prefix it with an `@`](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Code_Conversion_Guide#When_assigning_an_event_handling_entry_point.2C_prefix_it_with_an_.22.40.22) - even your error message is cited.

Comment: //Got some progress with your tip however new error message:
 
main.pas(57,38) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "<class method type of procedure(TObject) of object;Register>", expected "<procedure variable type of procedure(TObject) of object;Register>"
 
//Included one param
 
  t.OnTimer := @TTimerEvents.tonTimer(nil);
 
//Then new error
 
main.pas(57,17) Error: Variable identifier expected
 
// error with TTimerEvents in this line
 
 t.OnTimer := @TTimerEvents.tonTimer(nil);

Comment: You have to start reading and understanding error messages, and you have to re-read Ken's comment to understand why `TTimerEvents.tonTimer(nil)` is a call and not a pointer, while `:= @TTimerEvents.tonTimer` is the only way to assign procedure. And ask yourself if `class procedure` could be the culprit (like the error message says). And take the [tour] to learn about formattings here.

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you are probably testing Delphi code without enabling full Delphi compatibility mode with {$mode delphi}.